How to share a text file that is in the private directory of the application [Android 11 and above]
I have tried to implement the file provider approach and the detail for the same are given below:
xml file created for providing path
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="logs" path="logs/" />
    
</paths>

File provider added in manifest file
<provider
   android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
       android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>

Code for sharing the file
var directory = File(requireActivity().getFilesDir(), "logs")
var logFile = File(directory, "Log.txt")
if (logFile.exists()) {
    val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        requireContext(),
        requireActivity().packageName + ".fileprovider",
        logFile
    )

    val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain")
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri)
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    requireActivity().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share log file"))
}

When I share the file to Google drive via this approach then it just showed a notification that unable to schedule one file for upload. Tried other apps as well to share but none works.

That all looks good. Does Logcat show any informative messages from any of the apps (e.g., Google Drive) that you are sharing to?
